# Emulate Tablet using emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

I have widows 8.1 pro 64-bit machine, with windows sdk 8.1 installed on it, along with emulator and vs2013 express.

I am creating apps and run them on emulator, which emulates following devices:

---

### Device Index    | Device Name                       |

### 0              | Device                            |

### 1              | Emulator 8.1 U1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB |

### 2              | Emulator 8.1 U1 WVGA 4 inch       |

### 3              | Emulator 8.1 U1 WXGA 4.5 inch     |

### 4              | Emulator 8.1 U1 720P 4.7 inch     |

### 5              | Emulator 8.1 U1 1080P 5.5 inch    |

### 6              | Emulator 8.1 U1 1080P 6 inch      |

### 7              | Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB    |

### 8              | Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch          |

### 9              | Emulator 8.1 WXGA 4.5 inch        |

### 10             | Emulator 8.1 720P 4.7 inch        |

### 11             | Emulator 8.1 1080P 5.5 inch       |

### 12             | Emulator 8.1 1080P 6 inch         |

How to add more devices here. How to emulate windows tablet using this emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a WP8.1 project, you will only get phones for deploying/emulation.
Make an universal app or a separate windows8.1 project to deploy / test your code in the Win8.1 simulator.

UniversalApplications seem to be your solution here, hence you want to target both, phone and tablet/windows-store apps.

Answer (score 0):

if you work on universal application you should use emulator 8.1 
for windows phone 8 use the
 Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB |

8 | Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch |

9 | Emulator 8.1 WXGA 4.5 inch |

10 | Emulator 8.1 720P 4.7 inch |

11 | Emulator 8.1 1080P 5.5 inch |

12 | Emulator 8.1 1080P 6 inch |